# Transform Html DOM

Tags: elm

I am new to Elm and I really love it so far, but I've run into a problem that I cannot seem to wrap my head around.

I have an Html DOM, for example

```
div []
  [ h1 [] [text "Headline 1"]
  , p [] [text "Some text"]
  , h2 [] [text "Headline 2"]
  ]
```

I would like to add a-links inside each h[1-6] element and so transform it to something like (keeping it simple)

```
div []
  [ h1 [] [ text "Headline 1"
          , [a [name "headline"] [text "#"]
          ]
  , p [] [text "Some text"]
  , h2 [] [text "Headline 2"
          , [a [name "headline"] [text "#"]
          ]
  ]
```

This is conceptually not very hard. Look through the DOM, if element is h[1-6] add an a-link as child element. However my understanding of Elm is not well enough to get it to work.

Here is what I've been trying so far.

```
transform : Html a -> Html a
transform node =
    -- check if the tag is h1-h6
    case node.tag of
        -- add a-link to h1 children
        "h1" -> { node | children = (a [name "headline"] [text "#") :: node.children }
        "h2" -> { node | children = (a [name "headline"] [text "#") :: node.children }
        -- do this for all nodes in the tree
        _ -> { node | children = List.map transform node.children }
```

This doesn't work.

```
The type annotation for `transform` does not match its definition.

40| transform : Html a -> Html a
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type annotation is saying:

    VirtualDom.Node a -> VirtualDom.Node a

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    { b | tag : String, children : List (Html a) }
    -> { b | children : List (Html a), tag : String }
```

I understand that I can't do `node.tag` because the generic type `a` might not have that field. It wouldn't be type safe. For example the text node doesn't have a tag field, but is still an instance of `Html.Html a`.

```
> text "Hello World"
{ type = "text", text = "Hello World" } : Html.Html a
```

My question is, how can I do this? Can I do this? or shouldn't I be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to modify existing values of `Html msg` type.

They are final internal structures, which are rendered by [Virtual DOM](https://github.com/elm-lang/virtual-dom) in to actual HTML Nodes as an output of your program.

`Html msg` is an alias for `VirtualDom.Node a`

You are attempting to use them as Records, but that's just a JavaScript object.

Elm REPL outputs String presentation of an abstract data structure here:

```
> text "Hello World"
{ type = "text", text = "Hello World" } : Html.Html a -- not a record
```

Instead of attempting to transform `Html msg -> Html msg`, you should try something like:

```elm
-- Input example: [ "#", "http://google.com/", "http://package.elm-lang.org/" ]

linksView : List String -> Html msg
linksView links =
    links
        |> List.map (\link -> a [ href link ] [ text link ])
        |> div [] -- Expected output: <div> with thre links
```

Comment: I suspected that output was javascript. My "Html msg" comes from the output of `Markdown.toHtml` so I have no good way of manipulating it before it is returned as `Html msg` from `Markdown.toHtml`. Too bad its not possible to transform the output.

Answer (score 1):

In Elm, `Html a` is really only useful as output. You're never going to use it as input in the way that your `transform` function is attempting.

You will be better served by creating a model to describe your domain, then passing that to a `view` function to render html.

```elm
type alias Article =
  { priority : Priority
  , headline : String
  , body : String
  }

type alias Model =
  List Article

type Priority = First | Second
```

Your view could then look something like this:

```elm
view : Model -> Html msg
view =
  div [] << List.map viewArticle

viewArticle : Article -> Html msg
viewArticle article =
  let
    priorityTag =
      case article.priority of
        First -> h1
        Second -> h2
  in
    div []
      [ priorityTag []
        [ text article.headline
        , a [ name "headline" ] [ text "#" ]
        ]
      , p [] [ text article.body ]
      ]
```

Comment: As I commented to halfzebra, I have markdown content, that I transform to `Html msg` with `Markdown.toHtml`. I don't want the link in my markdown content, and apparently can't transform the output of `Markdown.toHtml` to add the link. That is a shame.

Comment: Gotcha. I was going to recommend extending the Markdown library but apparently that is just a wrapper around the JavaScript library https://github.com/chjj/marked

Comment: @Mikael Lundin Can you programmatically augment your Markdown before passing it to Markdown.toHtml?